# User re-login with batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, touch, pen

I have a batch file that modifies a registry entry. However, the changes do not get applied until the user does log-off and relog-in.
Is there any way that I can perform a relogin of the user automatically in the batch file?

Some more background information: Since Windows 8, one does not longer have the checkbox to disable the finger touch input but keep the digitalizer pen input working. However, it can be enabled and disabled through the following registry key: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Wisp\Touch\TouchGate`

Answer (score 1):

shutdown -l
or
shutdown -r

for help:  shutdown /?

Comment: `logoff` is shorter than `shutdown -l`.

Comment: The shutdown -l command seems to work so far. Is there a way to automatically login a user again? I'm just using a single user so I wouldn't even need any kind of user selection.

Comment: @Tectu: configure your Windows to automatically log in when your PC is turned on; here is a link for for [Windows 8](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows-8/fl/auto-logon-windows-8.htm); links to other Windows versions provided there